# Unmelt Pandas dataframe with multiple rows with the same ID (multiple measurements)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a melted dataframe that contains multiple values for the same id variables.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Val': [1,2,3,4]})

  ID  Val
0  A    1     
1  A    2       
2  B    3       
3  B    4
```

Using pivot results in an error because of repeated ID values:

```
df_unmelted=df.pivot(index="ID", values="Val", columns="ID")
ValueError: The name ID occurs multiple times, use a level number
```

I can manually add a repeat number in this small example to demonstrate the intended outcome but this does not work for the actual output with thousands of measurements and varying number of measurements per ID.

```
df["Repeat"] = [1,2,1,2]

  ID  Val  Repeat
0  A    1       1
1  A    2       2
2  B    3       1
3  B    4       2

df_unmelted = df.pivot(index="ID", values="Val", columns="Repeat")

Repeat  1  2
ID          
A       1  2
B       3  4
```

Is there a way to have pandas automatically number each recurrence when there are multiple values for the same ID?

Comment: add the "Repeat" with `df['Repeat'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()`